# How do I add a native static library (.a) to a Xamarin.Mac project

Tags: xamarin, native

Xamarin Mac has a folder called Native References. However, when adding native static libraries (.a), it seems to do absolutely nothing. Ideally I would like to use T exported methods by using DllImport("__Internal"....)

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This a rather late reply, but just in case anyone else comes across this in the future, note that currently it is not possible to use static `.a` libraries with Xamarin.Mac because Xamarin.Mac does not perform any native linking. That is, it does not invoke `clang` or `ld` at all during the build process. Instead, it just copies a *pre-built* "launcher" executable into the `Contents/MacOS/` folder in the `.app` bundle.

On the other hand, `.dylib` libraries should work, as long as they're compiled for x86 and have all their dependencies. I recently wrote up a little [guide on using dynamic libraries in Xamarin.Mac](http://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0004.html) that might be helpful.